# Android Studio Dynamically Appending a TextView to a ListView

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I am trying to do something similar to this chat in this tutorial (https://github.com/ScaleDrone/android-chat-tutorial), but I don't want to send sms messages.

Basically I want this program to have a listview of messages (just like the tutorial that has both messages from myself but from another person. Like you're texting someone).

It seems that the error comes from initializing the message_Body like in the java class.

```
TextView myMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_body);
```

When I debug it says that myMessage is null. Is there anyone that might be able to help me with debugging this issue? Thanks!

my_messages.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingVertical="10dp"
android:paddingRight="15dp"
android:paddingLeft="60dp"
android:clipToPadding="false">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/message_body"
    android:background="@drawable/my_message"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Placeholder message"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

their_message.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingVertical="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:paddingRight="60dp"
android:clipToPadding="false">

<View
    android:id="@+id/avatar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:layout_width="34dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/avatar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:text="Rose"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/message_body"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
    android:background="@drawable/their_message"
    android:paddingVertical="12dp"
    android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:text="How are you doing? This is a long message that should probably wrap."
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my java class I have this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    ListView view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mathListView);
    Intent in = getIntent();
    int index = in.getIntExtra("com.example.mathhack.ITEM_INDEX", -1);

    if (index > -1) {
        TextView myMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_body);
        List<TextView> textViewList = new ArrayList<TextView>();

        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<TextView>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, textViewList);
        myMessage.setText("test1");

        textViewList.add(myMessage);
        view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```